# Eclipse Android Emulator not working on Microsoft Surface Pro

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I cannot get an Android Virtual Device to launch on my Surface Pro.  I have had no problems on Windows XP, 7, or OS X.

I have tried launching from the AVD Manager, it opens the option dialog and when I select launch it acts like it is working, however the emulator never shows up.

When I select Run As Android Application from a project it acts like it is starting, once again nothing ever shows up.

Either way I get no error messages in the console.

I have tried disabling UAC.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click the program's icon and choose Properties.
2. When the Properties dialog box appears, click the Compatibility tab and then click the Run Compatibility Troubleshooter button.

Windows 8 tries to guess what version of Windows your program needs, and then it applies the changes. If the program begins working, you're through.

If the program still has trouble, though, move to Step 3.

1. In the Compatibility Mode section, select the Run This Program in Compatibility Mode For check box and select the program's desired Windows version from the drop-down list.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/1ael60/surface_pro_and_dj_software_also_android/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my question and answer here:

< [Android Emulator and AVD will not run on Surface Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331919/android-emulator-and-avd-will-not-run-on-surface-pro) >

As it turns out you can run the Android Emulator and AVD on the Microsoft Windows 8 Surface Pro.

You will need to rollback the graphic drivers:

< http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/latest-graphics-driver-update-makes-bluestacks/1f67d99f-3626-4110-aa22-773856b226cb > Method 1: I would suggest you to roll back to the previous driver.

a) Press Windows key + X on the keyboard. 
b) Click Device Manager. 
c) Double-click on Display Adapters. 
d) Double-click on your Graphic Card Drivers 
e) Select the Driver Tab 
f) Click on Roll Back Driver.

I still recommend using Bluestacks as an alternative method for Android Emulation.