# Android Emulator and AVD will not run on Surface Pro

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8, emulation

I have installed both the 64 and 32 bit versions of the Android SDK ADT Bundle and both the 64 and 32 bit versions of Java SE.

- I ran the AVD for the 64 bit version and with Windows 7 Compatibility Mode.
- I ran the AVD for the 32 bit version and with Windows XP (service pack 3) Compatibility Mode.

The emulator window will NOT open.

When I try to run from the command line in the correct directory:

```
emulator.exe -avd AVDName -gpu on
```

I get the error `emulator-arm.exe has stopped working`.

Can anyone who has successfully installed and ran the Android SDK ADT Bundle on the Windows 8 Surface Pro provide a solution on how to get the Android Emulator running?

Answer (score 3):

After serious research and internet searching I have found the perfect solution for Android Emulation on the Microsoft Windows 8 Surface Pro:

Bluestacks is great for running and testing .apk files compiled with the Android SDK ADT bundle and Eclipse IDE.

First follow these instructions to install Bluestacks successfully on the Surface Pro.  If the graphic drivers have been updated you may get a Bluestacks 25000 Graphics Card Error, if this is the case you will need to rollback your graphic drivers by doing the following:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/latest-graphics-driver-update-makes-bluestacks/1f67d99f-3626-4110-aa22-773856b226cb

Method 1: I would suggest you to roll back to the previous driver.

a)      Press Windows key + X on the keyboard.
b)      Click Device Manager.
c)       Double-click on Display Adapters.
d)      Double-click on your Graphic Card Drivers
e)      Select the Driver Tab 
f)       Click on Roll Back Driver.

Once you have finished the rollback you can install Bluestacks here:

http://cdn.bluestacks.com/downloads/0.7.9.850/BlueStacks-ThinInstaller_0.7.9.850_native.exe

Reference from here:

http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/bluestacks-releases-surface-pro-optimized-android-emulator

[Why does Android app run in small window on tablet emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398363/why-does-android-app-run-in-small-window-on-tablet-emulator)

Use the following in your Android App's Manifest file to ensure that your app will run in full screen:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

Use Bluestacks to open your .apk file.

You can even select and choose Bluestacks as your emulator through Eclipse and it is fully compatible.

I know this does not solve how to run the Android Emulator and AVD on the Surface Pro, but this is a fully functional and in my experience more efficient solution and replacement.  It is a shame you do not have specific device models to test with, however I feel that is a minor inconvenience for an actual working solution.

***UPDATE***

Upon completion of this article it just dawned on me that the rollback of the graphic drivers very well may have fixed the Android Emulator and AVD on the Surface Pro.  Lo and behold it did, now you can have the best of both worlds!

Comment: Thanks,  just rolling back the driver worked great for me. You saved me from a long day of configuration testing.

Answer (score 3):

The latest graphics drivers for your surface pro are buggy. Go to device manager->displayadapters and rightclick your graphics driver. Go to the driver tab en click on "roll back". I had the same problem with my surface pro. If you do not want to do this, Bluestacks is a good alternative.

Comment: Thank you, but I have provided a more sufficient answer to my own question two days ago.  Please up vote my answer if it helps.